# .htaccess how to block US without blocking searchengine crawlers (Uses cloudflare)

Tags: .htaccess, googlebot, cloudflare

Currently in my htaccess I have this

```
    SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry US UnwantedCountry=1
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from env=UnwantedCountry
    <Files /error/403.html> 
    Allow From All 
    </Files>
```

It blocks US from accessing this part of the site but I want search engines (mostly google) to still be able to index it

Comment: solved by adding         SetEnvIf From ^googlebot\(at\)googlebot\.com$ !UnwantedCountry
Waiting till I can answer my own question